# Reformatting a JSON API Response From Ethermine.org

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests

I am writing a python script which calls the API of ethermine.org, then I am using telegraf to input the data into influxdb and it is being displayed on grafana.
Influxdb and telegraf accepts json format and the first two API pulls which I did work, they display the data in the following format(I put x's in place of the actual values that get returned):

```
{"time": xxx, "lastSeen": xxx, "reportedHashrate": xxx, "currentHashrate": xxx, "validShares": x, "invalidShares": 0, "staleShares": 0, "averageHashrate": x, "activeWorkers": x, "unpaid": xx, "unconfirmed": null, "coinsPerMin": xxxx, "usdPerMin": xxxx, "btcPerMin": xxxx}
```

However, the 3rd pull which I am trying to do seems to be outputting an extra '}' character and also seems to be formatted slightly differently(instead of just a tag like currentHashrate and a value it has a tag say price: then {two more tags} so almost like a list of tags within the price category, which is where I think the extra '}' might be coming from.

```
{"topMiners": [], "minedBlocks": [{"number": x, "miner": "x", "time": x}, {"number": x, "miner": "x", "time": x}, {"number": x, "miner": "x", "time": x}, {"number": x, "miner": "x", "time": x}, {"number": x, "miner": "x", "time": x}, {"number": x, "miner": "x", "time": x}, {"number": x, "miner": "x", "time": x}, {"number": x, "miner": "x", "time": x}, {"number": x, "miner": "x", "time": x}, {"number": x, "miner": "x", "time": x}], "poolStats": {"hashRate": x, "miners": x, "workers": x, "blocksPerHour": x}, "price": {"usd": xxx, "btc": xxx}}
```

Please note I am new to python so in my attempt to fix it using google I was unsuccessful as I am probably going about it the wrong way. I will upload screenshots of the error I am getting in telegraf, then also a screenshot of the python error I got when I attempted to fix it. Also find my code of the python script below

[image]

python error which relates to these lines of code I think

```
print(statsPool.text)
poolS=json.loads(statsPool.text)
print(f'{poolS["price"]}')
```

[image]

```
import json
import requests

# Miner - Statistics Armand
keyArmand = 'xxxxxxxxxx'
urlArmand = 'https://api.ethermine.org/miner/' + keyArmand + '/currentStats'


# Miner - Statistics Altus
keyAltus = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
urlAltus = 'https://api.ethermine.org/miner/' + keyAltus + '/currentStats'

# PoolStats
urlPoolStats = 'https://api.ethermine.org' + '/poolStats'

#call 1
statsArmand = requests.get(urlArmand)
#call 2
statsAltus = requests.get(urlAltus)
#call 3
statsPool = requests.get(urlPoolStats)

print(json.dumps(json.loads(statsArmand.text)['data']))
print(json.dumps(json.loads(statsAltus.text)['data']))

#problem line (prints an extra '}' at the end
print(json.dumps(json.loads(statsPool.text)['data']))

#next 3 lines is what I tried to do to fix it (either need to get rid of the extra '}' at the end or I just need the price tag displayed in the correct format
print(statsPool.text)
poolS=json.loads(statsPool.text)
print(f'{poolS["price"]}')
```

As a summary: The 3rd python json API call is returning a different format to the first two, I would like to either reformat the 3rd one in the same format as the first two or just extract the price in USD(price: "USD" part) in the format (similar to say {"time": xxx}), because that is the only part I want to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with `requests.get()` on an API that returns data in JSON format, you probably want `requests` to handle the data for you rather than accessing it as text and parsing it manually.

Since the returned JSON object contains nested JSON objects, you would have to manually parse each of the nested objects (e.g. using `json.loads()`) when you get it as text.

In the call to `requests.get(urlPoolStats)`, the returned JSON object contains another JSON object, which is not parsed in your case, when calling `json.loads(statsPool.text)`, which is most likely why it's failing when you try to access `price`.

A call to [`requests.get()`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.get) returns a [`Response` object](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response) which implements a [`json()` method](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.json) which will parse the data correctly for you and return it as a Pyton `dict` with all the nested JSON objects accessible as keys in the `dict`.

In other words, instead of

```python
json.dumps(json.loads(statsPool.text)['data'])
```

what you want to do is

```python
statsPool.json()['data']
```

This returns a Python `dict` and you can now get the price like this:

```python
statsPool.json()['data']['price']
```

Comment: Thank you that makes sense, however I am still confused on one thing: to test I replaced my working ```print(json.dumps(json.loads(statsAltus.text)['data']))``` with
```print(statsAltus.json()['data'])``` it runs fine in python itself, it now outputs ```{'time': xxx, 'lastSeen': xxx, 'reportedHashrate': xxx, 'currentHashrate': xxx, 'validShares': xx, 'invalidShares': x, 'staleShares': x, 'averageHashrate': xxx, 'activeWorkers': x, 'unpaid': xxx, 'unconfirmed': None, 'coinsPerMin': xxx, 'usdPerMin': xxx, 'btcPerMin': xxx}```
Running out of characters, continuing on next comment

Comment: However, when running it inside telegraf I get an error like this: 
https://gyazo.com/7bc6b8d0ed6aa4f6530a2092ad34fdcd
```2021-03-01T10:29:08Z I! Starting Telegraf 1.17.3
2021-03-01T10:29:08Z E! [inputs.exec] Error in plugin: invalid character '\'' lo                               oking for beginning of object key string
```
Not sure why, I don't see any '\' character...I will post It to the telegraf forums if it is not applicable to stack overflow, but maybe you can help here as well

Comment: It hard to tell without seeing the code but my guess would be that the API you are feeding the data in is expecting a different data type. Concretely, that might mean that the API expects data as a Python `dict` but you are passing in a string containing JSON, or something like that.

Comment: Keep in mind, that Python `dict`s and JSON objects represented as strings, even though they look very similar, are different things.

Comment: what code would you need to see to get a better picture? I can link telegraf's documentation (https://docs.influxdata.com/telegraf/v1.17/data_formats/input/json/) , but I think it might be better if I ask on their forum

Comment: I don't know Telegraf's API, so the question is:
How and where _exactly_ are you passing in the data?
Is it happening (automatically) in your Python code?
Is it happening (automatically/manually) on the command line?
Is it happening (manually) in the web browser?
In other words, what are the exact steps that are leading to the error that you have shared?

Comment: I think I found the reason, the code you gave my returns a python dict, but with single quotes ' ', the plugin I am using expects it in json format which has " " double quotes...is there a way to modify the code you gave so that it achieves this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229342/discussion-between-altus-cilliers-and-p3j4p5).